# How to output the results of a calculation

Tags: java

I am trying to print out the result of invoking the `calcula` method as shown in the code below, but when I print the `toString()` the result I have is this IKCV @ 2a139a55. It seems like I must rewrite the `toString()` method in my IKCV class, but do not know how to implement it. How do I get the results of my method invocation to print out correctly?

My Test Class:

```
public class testaTemplateMethod {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Orcamento orcamento = new Orcamento(500);
    IKCV ikcv = new IKCV();
    ikcv.calcula(orcamento);
    System.out.println(ikcv);
  }
}
```

and the class where I think I should implement my method `toString()`

```
public class IKCV extends TemplateDeImpostoCondicional {

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    ?????????????????????
  } 

  double calcula(Orcamento orcamento) {
    return 0.0; // Obviously not the real implementation
  }

}
```

Comment: You should probably add the language tag (C#?); also,what does this mean: "so I can print ikcv ( double)." ? Print ikcv?!?

Comment: Please have a look on this [howto](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It helps you to ask a good question. At the moment it is very difficult to understand what your question is.

Comment: Sorry, this was my first post

Comment: Did you try replacing `??????` with `return "fancy";`? Did your program print `fancy` then instead of `IKCV @ 2a139a55`? You probably don't want to see `fancy` so you'll have to replace it by what you actually want to see. But you didn't *specify the desired output in your question* so I don't know what you actually want to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh! No, you don't need to override `toString()`. You just want to print out the results of the calculation, don't you?

Just do something like this:

```
public class testaTemplateMethod {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Orcamento orcamento = new Orcamento(500);
        IKCV ikcv = new IKCV();
        ikcv.calcula(orcamento);
        System.out.println("Calcula: " + ikcv.calcula(orcamento));
        // or ikcv.minimaTaxacao(orcamento) or whatever
    }
}
```

You don't print out the object itself, just print out the result of the method invocation that you care about.

Comment: Yes!! Thanks, I was trying to print the ikcv only . I apologize for my inexperience , I'm starting now , I try to improve my questions

Comment: I suggest editing the post so that people searching for toString-Overloads will not accidently find this.

Answer (score 0):

Just construct any string representing your data inside the overridden toString function and return it. For example, just try `return "[IKCV Object]";`.